# Set Theory and Expected Value problem

Tags: expected-value

For any subset $S\subseteq\{1,2,\ldots,15\}$, call a number $n$ an anchor for $S$ if $n$ and $n+\#(S)$ are both elements of $S$. For example, $4$ is an anchor of the set $S=\{4,7,14\}$, since $4\in S$ and $4+\#(S) = 4+3 = 7\in S$.

Given that $S$ is randomly chosen from all $2^{15}$ subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,15\}$ (with each subset being equally likely), what is the expected value of the number of anchors of $S$?

I don't know how to start this problem.

Comment: The tag [tag:set-theory] is not appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

> "...I don't know how to start this problem."

For $n\in\left\{ 1,2,\dots,15\right\} $ let $a_{n}$ denotes the
number of subsets of $\left\{ 1,2,\dots,15\right\} $ with the property
that $n$ is an anchor of it.

Further let $X_{n}$ take value $1$ if $n$ is an anchor of the randomly chosen  $S$
and let it take value $0$ otherwise.

Then $X:=X_{1}+\cdots+X_{15}$ is the number of anchors of $S$ and
with linearity of expectation we find:

$\mathbb{E}X=\sum_{n=1}^{15}\mathbb{E}X_{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{15}P\left(X_{n}=1\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{15}P\left(n\text{ is an anchor of }S\right)=2^{-15}\sum_{n=1}^{15}a_{n}$

Now it remains to find the $a_{n}$.

Maybe you should first give that a try yourself.